# how to achieve movement of multiple or list rectangles drawn on picture box or on image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, c#-4.0

i want to move rectangles in x direction by button click , i have 9 rectangles on my image , kindly check the below code and let me know how i can move all rectangles in x or y direction  .

i'm getting new rectangle here  , but old rectangle should disappear and all the rectangle must overlap and move together in all direction . 
How can i achieve that .

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // listRec has 9 rectangles .
        Rectangle[] recn = listRec.ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {

            Rectangle newrec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();

            newrec.X = recn[i].X + j;
            newrec.Y = recn[i].Y;
            newrec.Width = recn[i].Width;
            newrec.Height = recn[i].Height;
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(newrec.X, newrec.Y,newrec.Width, newrec.Height));
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rect);

            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            //ra[0].Location.X = newrec(ra[0].X+10,ra[0].Y,ra[0].Width,ra[0].Height);

        }
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        this.Invalidate();


        j = j + 10;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Update the position of all your rectangles then `Invalidate()` your PictureBox so it redraws itself?  What is the issue here?...

Comment: @Idle_Mind , when i try to move rectangle by   mouse , only one rectangle is moving , i want to move all the rectangles . how can i do that . i have added all rectangles  to the list . can you please give me some idea to do further.